# stuck in recursion- find the lowest differnce

Tags: java, recursion

i got the following exercise:
given an array of ints, return the lowest absolute differnece between two groups of differnt numbers from the array in recursion.
for example : if you have the following array: {5,4,2} the lowest differnce is 1 because if you split it to two groups: {5}, {4,2} you get : Math.abs(5-6)=1.
another example: if you have the following array: {4,3,2,1} the lowest differnce is 0 because if you split it to two groups: {4,1}, {3,2} you get : Math.abs(5-5)=0.
this has to be in recursion only and you can create as much methods as you like.
the method signature is : 
public static int minDiff(int[] arr)

what i got is this :

```
public static int minDiff(int[] arr){
    return minDiff(arr,0,0,0,arr[0]);
}
private static int minDiff(int[] arr,int index,int groupa, int groupb, int diff){
    if(index>=arr.length || arr.length-1-index<0 || (index==arr.length-1-index) ) return diff;
    int dif1=minDiff(arr,index+1,groupa+arr[index], groupb, diff);
    int dif2=minDiff(arr,index+1,groupa, groupb+arr[index], diff);
    if(Math.abs(dif1-dif2)<diff){
        diff=Math.abs(dif1-dif2);
    }
    return diff;

}
```

please advise

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: what i am doing wrong ....

Comment: What happens and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Do you have to split the whole array into 2 groups?
 For example {5,6,10, 14} could yield (5-6) = 1.

Also, Do the numbers have to be adjacent to each other to be considered a group? Could {5,10,6} yield {5+6} and {10} to make (11-10) = 1?

Comment: @shockawave123 no they dont have to be adjacent, yet you have to use all of the numbers in array, so every number in array must be used in calculation and be only one time in a certain group ( cant be in both of them)

Comment: Cool. I'd suggest updating your question. I'd use a different example that shows that order doesn't matter. You could use my {5,10,6} example.

Comment: You are assigning `diff` to the first element of the input array.  What if the array was {1, 10, 20}  `diff` will always be set as 1. If you are going to set `diff` to a default value, you'll have to make sure its greater than the highest value of the array.

Comment: @shockawave123 what, in your opinion is the stopping condition to make the recursion to stop

Comment: @Meni i think the stopping conditions are correct. When do you  compare `groupA` and `groupB`? You seem to compare the `diff`, which uses other `diffs`, but the `diff` should be using the Abs difference of the groups.

Comment: @Meni on second thought i think the stopping conditions aren't correct. I think you just need one `if(index >= (arr.length))`

Comment: This is not just about finding the Lowest Difference, but rather it is about  finding the Tightest Bound you can ever come up with. This means the Tightest Bound are supposed to be 0, or 1 or -1. Therefore, when you are grouping your Elements to a certain group. You should always pick groups that when you add all of its elements should results in 0 or 1 or -1. So if you have Group A and B then A = 5 and B = 5 will always give you the tightest bound after subtraction; because A - B = 5 - 5 = 0.

Comment: About Recursions: What stops recursion is after adding the elements of the two groups. Then when you subtract Group A - B. You should get 0 or 1 or -1. thus if  A - B == 0 || A - B == 1 || A - B == -1     then stop.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(minDiff(new int[] { 5, 2, 4 })); // 1
    System.out.println(minDiff(new int[] { 5, 4, 2 })); // 1
    System.out.println(minDiff(new int[] { 1, 2, 7, 17, 6 })); // 1
    System.out.println(minDiff(new int[] { 4, 3, 2, 1 })); // 0

}

public static int minDiff(int[] arr)
{
    return minDiff(arr, 0, 0, 0);
}

private static int minDiff(int[] arr, int sumGroupA, int sumGroupB, int i)
{
    if (i == arr.length) // in case we are out of boundaries return the absolute value between the two groups
        return Math.abs(sumGroupA - sumGroupB);

    int r1 = minDiff(arr, sumGroupA + arr[i], sumGroupB, i + 1); // add to group 1
    int r2 = minDiff(arr, sumGroupA, sumGroupB + arr[i], i + 1); // add to group 2 instead

    return Math.min(r1, r2);
}
```